# c# reader.HasRows returning false

Tags: c#, mysql

For some reason the query below is not returning any results, if I run the query directly in mysql with the query from Console.Write(query), it returns the row successfully. When I step through it, it never gets passed reader.HasRows. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

```
        if (dbUtilsManf.openConnection(mConnection) == true)
        {
            string query = "SELECT * from table WHERE code = '" + code + "'";
            Console.Write(query);

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, mConnection);

            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("did it get here?");
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                  // do stuff


                }
            }
```

Comment: This code is vulnerable to SQL Injection, go fix that.

Comment: Try putting some breakpoints. You may not even be reaching the `if (reader.HasRows)` line..

Comment: Thanks, this is just a generic query, once I resolve this issue I will fix that when I rewrite the query.

Comment: Is your table name "table"? you want to put the actual table name there,

"SELECT * FROM beerTable WHERE beerType = 'IPA'"

Comment: 2 points: is the outer `if` ever entered ? Then hardcode the query instead of using string concatenation, at least as a first step towards debug.

Comment: I see you're trying to meet Robert (a.k.a. Little Bobby Tables) http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @dub stylee, it does hit the if (reader.HasRows) line, but doesn't go into it

Comment: Make sure you are using the actual table name. `TABLE` is reserved in MySQL, so I don't imagine that is your actual table name...

Comment: My table name isn't table, I just used that name to post on here. I'm running the query directly into mysql and it works fine, so I think the problem is with c# not the query

Comment: Well, there is nothing inherently wrong with the code above (other than the SQL injection vulnerability). Usually in a case like this, the database is not configured correctly to allow the connection from your application.

Comment: Could it be because I'm using multiple readers in different methods? I'm closing the readers, but that's the only culprit I can think of.